# Error when selecting records with max date per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to run the code below I get the following error,
**"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."** I am not understanding why this query is returning an error when I have run a similar query only not using the date. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
SELECT *
FROM [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION] AS CLASS_DEV
WHERE (CLASS_DEV.State, Eff_Date) = (SELECT State, Max(Eff_Date) FROM [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that SQL Server supports the `IN` clause with multiple columns (though MySQL does).  But we can just use `TOP` here:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION]
ORDER BY Eff_Date DESC;
```

Actually, I think a literal translation of your query would use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, so you may try this instead of what I wrote above if you want all records possibly tied with the maximum effective date.

If you instead wanted to find the record for each state having the most recent effective date, then we can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY State ORDER BY Eff_Date DESC) rn
    FROM [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION] 
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Again, if you want the ties you may replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support tuples with `in`.  One alternative with no subqueries is:

```
select top (1) with ties w.*
from [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION] w
order by rank() over (partition by state order by eff_date desc);
```

Another method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select w.*
from [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION] w
where w.eff_date = (select max(w2.eff_date)
                    from [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION] w2
                    where w2.state = w.state
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually without sample input/output data, it would be a little a bit hard to send you the best and correct query.

But as it is shown in the error message and your given query, it is obvious that you can not have tuple structure in `Where` clause...

You need to rewrite your query using one of the pre-mentioned methods or the following way:

```
SELECT CLASS_DEV1.*
FROM [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION] AS CLASS_DEV1
    INNER JOIN [Rating_Sandbox_Dev].[dbo].[TBL_WC_DEVIATION] AS CLASS_DEV2
        ON CLASS_DEV1.State = CLASS_DEV2.State
GROUP BY CLASS_DEV1.State,
         CLASS_DEV1.Eff_Date
HAVING MAX(CLASS_DEV2.Eff_Date) = CLASS_DEV1.Eff_Date
```